# How to compile skia on Windows

Tags: skia, skiasharp

I tried compiling skia on Windows as suggested in https://skia.org/user/build

1. `bin/gn gen out/Static --args='is_official_build=true'`
2. `ninja -C out/Static`

Build fails to find libjpeg.h, libpng.h

Then I added following line in gn args

```
extra_cflags = ["-I ../../third_party/externals/libpng/", "-I ../../third_party/externals/libjpeg-turbo/"]
```

It still fails to find both the headers.

But the point is that I should not pass include path because it should be handled internally if JPEG/PNG is core part of skia.

How do I build it on Windows?

Comment: anyone please help..

Comment: this may help: https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/wiki/Building-on-Linux and then specifically for Windows: https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp/blob/605946352e543ee39345bb4969db28ddf2ae4977/cake/BuildExternals.cake#L95-L101

Comment: Probably the most important thing to take out is the `skia_use_system_libjpeg_turbo=false` and others like it. Windows does not have a system libjpeg library, so you MUST use the internal one (or manage it elsewhere)

Comment: @Matthew thanks, i could compile skia using your hint.

Answer (score 11):

I did it like here:

```
bin/gn gen out/Static --args='is_debug=false is_official_build=true skia_use_system_expat=false skia_use_system_libjpeg_turbo=false skia_use_system_libpng=false skia_use_system_libwebp=false skia_use_system_zlib=false skia_use_system_icu=false skia_use_system_harfbuzz=false'
```

Under windows 10 x64

Answer (score 3):

I could compile skia on windows using following args

```
gn gen out/Static --args='is_debug=false is_official_build=true skia_use_system_expat=false skia_use_system_libjpeg_turbo=false skia_use_system_libpng=false skia_use_system_libwebp=false skia_use_system_zlib=false'
```

Comment: What are you building for? For pure skia or are you going to use SkiaSharp?